# Aborted (dumped core)

Tags: c++, coredump

```
./product -rows 4 -cols 4
```

I'm getting this error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Abort (core dumped)
```

And this is my code..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;


int **create_array(int rows, int cols){
   int x, y;
   int **array = new int *[rows];
    for(int i = 0; i < cols; i++){
       array[i] = new int[cols];
    }
    array[x][y] = 1+rand()%100;
    cout << array << endl;
    return array;
}  
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int rows, cols;
    int **my_array = create_array(rows, cols);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `rows` and `cols` are uninitialized, this is undefined behaviour and they might contain unexpected values.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where you initialize the variables `rows` and `cols` in `main`.

Once you fix that, `x` and `y` inside `create_array` are afflicted with the same problem. If the object is to fill the array with pseudo-random values, you don't need `x` since `i` is already marching through your 2D array (whose vector-of-pointers based representation is known as the [Iliffe vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iliffe_vector), by the way). You just need to introduce some `j` which marches through each row of the array. This `j` would be stepped in a loop that is nested inside the existing loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
   array[i] = new int[cols];       // allocate row
   for (int j = 0; i < cols; j++)  // loop over it and fill it
     array[i][j] = 1 + rand()%100;
}
```

There is another issue in that your major loop, which should be allocating **rows** of the array, is looping `i` from `0` to `i < cols`.  This should be `i < rows`.  Inside the loop, you allocate a row whose size is `[cols]`, which is correct. In my snipped above, I made the correction, if you look closely.